# Java Timer to call function n times after every t seconds

Tags: java, timer

I want Java Timer to call function n times after every t seconds. I am trying this right now it calls function after every t seconds but I want this function to be called for only n times.

```
Timer tt = new Timer();
tt.schedule(new MyTimer(url), t);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Timer` doesn't have it as a built-in function. You will need to add a counter to count it for each call and then stop the timer using `cancel()` after n times.

Something like this:

```
final int[] counter = {n};
final Timer tt = new Timer();
tt.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
        //your job
        counter[0]--;
        if (counter[0] == 0) {
            tt.cancel();
        }
    }
}, t);
```

Comment: You are decrementing `n` and then checking `counter`? How do you suppose this will work? You need `final int[] counter = {n}` and then `counter[0]--` and then `if (counter[0] == 0)`. It is also better to have `Timer` as a long-running object and submit new `TimerTask`s to it (and cancel the `TimerTask`s).

Comment: Decrementing `n` was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out and fixed now. Regarding the `Timer` or `TimerTask` should be canceled, I think that depends on the program requirement. If the program should exist right after n jobs, then the `Timer` should be canceled. If the program will be running continuously and `Timer` will be reused, you are totally right that the `TimerTask` should be canceled. Why counter should be an array tho?

Comment: Did you try compiling that code? Now you are trying to decrement a final var. You can't close over non-final local var so I showed you the standard trick to get around that.

Comment: I didn't really code it. I was just trying to show an idea. You are correct about the final var decrement and I just fixed in the example above. +1 for your comment. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for fixing the example :) It is after all a much more useful answer when it's correct and shows all the tricks involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) Service. You have to count youself, how often you called the Callable and cancel the Timer.