# How can I execute a method every x second for y time in java

Tags: java, timer

I want to execute a method every second for 20 times.

Actually I have timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
int begin = 0;
int timeInterval = 1000;

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call the method
    }
}, begin, timeInterval);
```

How can I call a method 20 times with this interval?

Comment: loop with 20 iterations and `Thread.sleep(1000);`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer use .sleep with care, it does not guarantee accurate timing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `timer.schedule()`, and keep track of how many times the timer was executed, and stop the timer after 20 times, with `timer.cancel()`

[java doc - time schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
>   beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place
>   at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.
>
> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the
>   actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is
>   delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background
>   activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well. In the long
>   run, the frequency of execution will generally be slightly lower than
>   the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock
>   underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).
>
> Fixed-delay execution is appropriate for recurring activities that
>   require "smoothness." In other words, it is appropriate for activities
>   where it is more important to keep the frequency accurate in the short
>   run than in the long run. This includes most animation tasks, such as
>   blinking a cursor at regular intervals. It also includes tasks wherein
>   regular activity is performed in response to human input, such as
>   automatically repeating a character as long as a key is held down.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> task - task to be scheduled.
> delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
> period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
> ```

## Example

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
int begin = 0;
int timeInterval = 1000;
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  int counter = 0;
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //call the method
       counter++;
       if (counter >= 20){
         timer.cancel();
       }
   }
}, begin, timeInterval);
```

Comment: you could combine the increment and the comparison with: `if (++counter >= 20)`

Comment: This is a good answer. Thank you for sharing your example code. Work like a charm.

Comment: @Lino I think clean code principles are better to follow.

Comment: @Adam IMO does incremening a variable inside an if condition count as clean code, as the variable is only used for said if-statement

Comment: @dudi Glad to help :)

Comment: @Lino Didn't mean it was a certain principle, but could be misleading for a beginner.

Comment: Assuming it’s not time sensitive, incrementing a counter is okay, but timers only guarantee “at least” interval. Personally I’d use Duration to calculate the running time, but that’s me 

Answer (score 2):

Try the Executor Service. You have to count youself, how often you called the Callable and cancel the Timer.

**If it does not meet your requirements, you can follow this thread:**

[Java Timer to call function n times after every t seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590322/1406172)

Comment: Good solution, but in this case you'll have to loop and add the same `Callable` to the executor 20 times. I think using `java.util.Timer` feels nicer.

Comment: @Adam Timer can be sensitive to changes in the system clock

Comment: This anser could be improved with an example, perhaps one using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Otherwise I agree, using an `ExecutorService` is preferrable nowadays, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice